# WebView does not recognize history state in some cases

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

In my Android app I implemented a common approach to "go back on back-button pressed":

```java
private WebView webView; // my WebView

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

But today I noticed a weird thing. If, on the very first webpage loaded on `webView`, it calls `history.pushState(...)` automatically, then `webView.canGoBack()` will return `false`, causing the approach above to fail (even if I execute `webView.goBack()` directly, nothing happens in the webView), although executing `history.back()` still works within the webpage itself. I've also tried calling `history.pushState` automatically using `setTimeout`, with the same result. However, if `history.pushState` is called manually, i.e. triggered by some user events, then `webView.canGoBack()` is `true` and the code works.

It seems to me that this is a bug of WebViews. Any ideas?